# Removing specific numbers using regex in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

To illustrate my problem with an example, in the following paragraph,

> 1.If we may believe the Egyptians, Hephaestus was the son of the Nile, and with him philosophy began, priests and prophets being its chief exponents. 2. Hephaestus lived 48,863 years before Alexander of Macedon, and in the interval there occurred 373 solar and 832 lunar eclipses. The date of the Magians, beginning with Zoroaster the Persian, was 5000 years before the fall of Troy, as given by Hermodorus the Platonist in his work on mathematics; but Xanthus the Lydian reckons 6000 years from Zoroaster to the expedition of Xerxes, and after that event he places a long line of Magians in succession, bearing the names of Ostanas, Astrampsychos, Gobryas, and Pazatas, down to the conquest of Persia by Alexander,

I want to remove the "1." and "2.", but not the "373", "832", or any of the other numbers. The document contains much more than just this example, so just removing single digit numbers won't work. I assume this is fairly straightforward, but I'm new to using regex and I've been finding it difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find `\d+\.` and replace with empty string.

Comment: You might want to use `(?<=\s)\d+\.(?=\s)` instead to only find stand-alone numbers with periods and not also remove digits from floating-point numbers, e.g '12.34'.

Comment: I know this is a "meta" question (and I'll delete it), but would you mind if I ask whether you use any software to notify you of new questions or whether you just happened to do a refresh shortly after this question was posted?

Comment: This seems to work. Njol's suggestion is probably more thorough, but in my case it doesn't look like the text has any numbers like that. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Don't you see get some sort of notification when there's a new question (or more)? It doesn't work on the main question page (I guess because of the big amount of new questions), but it works in different tags.